# Checking the meaning in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, grammaticality, adjectives, sequence-of-tenses

Someone I know who is at college and I'm asking him few questions. What is written inside the brackets is what I want to check its applicability.

You seem young, are you (at/in) your second year.

You got right I'm (at/in) my second year. (I still have 3 years ahead ).

Answer (score 1):

The right preposition is "in" for both sentences. You also say "**in** the third/eighth/etc grade".

At least in the US, it is customary to refer to the years of a 4-year college degree by the following names:

- freshman year = first year
- sophomore year = second year
- junior year = third year
- senior year = fourth year

Someone in their sophomore year in college, for example, is called a "sophomore". So a more idiomatic way of saying "Are you in your second year?" would be "Are you a sophomore?"

"You got right" is incorrect, you can either say "You *are* right" (almost always contracted to "**You're** right" in everyday conversation), or "You got that right" which is a bit informal.

Comment: Those names for college years are not used in British English. We would say "Are you in your second year?.

Comment: @RuslanD Thank you a lot for the great explanation.